# htaccess: php language variable on index page

Tags: php, .htaccess, clean-urls, lang, trailing-slash

I'm trying to clean up urls from extensions and php get language variables:

test.com/en/ => test.com/?lang=en

test.com/ro/page/ => test.com/page.php?lang=ro

Here is my .htaccess:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8

Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f  [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .* - [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^.]+)\.php  /$2.php?lang=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

While it transforms test.com/ro/page => test.com/page.php?lang=ro
And test.com/ro/index => test.com/index.php?lang=ro

I cannot get it to transform index page test.com/en/ => test.com/?lang=en

Can you guys please help me to achieve this?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to route everything to `index.php` and include the right files from there?

Comment: At this stage, when website is finished and its structure is already set up, fixing htaccess file will probably be the easiest option.

Comment: Just a suggestion :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right under this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^.]+)\.php  /$2.php?lang=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

try adding this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]{2})/?$ /?lang=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```